# Slick slider dynamic content won't resize height

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slick.js

I have a slick slider with adaptiveHeight.

The slider contains a multistep form and some fields are conditional and it's possible for error messages to pop-up.

When I display error messages or conditional fields, the height of the slide won't adapt, resulting in some fields to be cropped off.

When i resize the window, the slider resizes to the right height.

I've tried triggering the window resize event without any success.

Has anyone a solution for this problem?

Code Example: [Codepen - Slick dynamic height changes](https://codepen.io/mschuler/pen/BaQMjQB)

```
$('#dynamic').on('change', function() {
  $('.dynamic').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

As soon as you toggle the dynamic content, the rest of the form will be cut off.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @mahan Sorry for the lacking code. I hope my Codepen example clarifys my problem.
As soon as you toggle "show text" the rest of the form fields get cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slider sets fixed height on `div.slick-list.draggable`. You need to give `div.slick-list.draggable` the same height as the first slide - `div[data-slick-index="0"]`.

```
  var height = $('div[data-slick-index="0"]').outerHeight(true);
  $(".slick-list.draggable").height(height)
```

Use the above code in  `$('#dynamic').on('change' () =>{})`

```
$('#dynamic').on('change', function() {
  $('.dynamic').toggleClass('visible');
  var height = $('div[data-slick-index="0"]').outerHeight(true);
  $(".slick-list.draggable").height(height)
});
```

---

Use this code should you want to have a similar animation as Slider.

```
  $(".slick-list.draggable").animate({height: height})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was pretty much what i was looking for.